# Multiplicity of relationship changes in Entity Framework 6 from 1-to-many to 1-to-0 or 0..1

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

I am working with two entities County and Patient which have a 1 to many relationship.

```
public class County
{
   public int CountyId { get; set; }  // Primary Key
   public string CountyName { get; set; ) // A unique index column
   public virtual ICollection<Patient> Patients { get; set; }
}

public class CountyMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<County>
{
    public CountyMap()
    {
        ToTable("Counties");
        HasKey(c => c.CountyId);
        Property(c => c.CountyId).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
            Property(c => c.CountyName).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(50).HasColumnAnnotation("Index",
                new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("IX_Counties", 1) { IsUnique = true }));
    }
}

public class Patient
{
    public int PatientId { get; set; }
    public string PatientLastName { get; set; }
    public string PatientFirstName { get; set; }
    public string CountyName { get; set; }
    public int CountyId { get; set; } // Foreign key to Counties table
    public virtual County County { get; set; } // Navigation property
}

public class PatientMap: EntityTypeConfiguration<Patient>
{
    public PatientMap()
    {
            ToTable("Patients");
            HasKey(p => p.PatientId);
            Property(p => p.PatientId).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
            Property(p => p.PatientLastName).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(50);
            Property(p => p.PatientFirstName).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(50);
            Property(p => p.CountyId).IsRequired();
            HasRequired(p => p.County).WithMany(c => c.Patients).HasForeignKey(p => p.CountyId);
    }
}

public class AppContext : DbContext
{
    public AppContext()
        : base("name=AppContext")
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<County> Counties { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Patient> Patients { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CountyMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new PatientMap());
    }
}

public class PatientUOW
{
    public Patient CreatePatient(Patient patient)
    {
        string errorMessage = String.Empty;
        Patient patientReturned = null;
        County county = null;

        try
        {
           using (AppContext ctx = new AppContext())
           {
               // ONLY Pre-existing counties are permitted
                county = ctx.Counties.Where(c => c.CountyName == patient.CountyName).SingleOrDefault<County>();

                county.Patients.Add(patient);
                ctx.SaveChanges();  // An exception is thrown here

           }
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

The exception message is:

> Multiplicity constraint violated. The role 'Patient_County_Target' of
>   the relationship 'ArielOperations.Domain.Concrete.Patient_County' has
>   multiplicity 1 or 0..1.

The debugger on the County entity shows:

[image]

and
[image]

Can anyone explain what is happening here?  I've seen several entries here and elsewhere and none seem to work.

Thank you.

Comment: Why does `Patient` have a `CountyName`? That's redundant.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve my issue.  The key seems to be to avoid attempting to create a new County record when adding a Patient in a County. To achieve this I did not pass a County instance to the CreatePatient method.  The new Patient only contains the CountyId of the target County.

```
Patient newPatient = new Patient
{
    PatientLastName = "Doe",
    PatientFirstName = "Jane",
    CountyName = "Denton",
    CountyId = 4
};
```

We can now pass this newPatient instance to the CreatePatient method.

```
public Patient CreatePatient(Patient patient)
{
    string errorMessage = String.Empty;
    Patient patientReturned = null;
    County county = null;

    try
    {
            using (AppContext ctx = new AppContext())
           {
               // ONLY Pre-existing counties are permitted
                county = ctx.Counties.Where(c => c.CountyName == patient.CountyName).SingleOrDefault<County>();
                ctx.Patients.Add(patient);
                ctx.SaveChanges();
                patientReturned = patient;
           }
    } // end try
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        errorMessage = err.Message;
    } // end catch (Exception err)

    return patientReturned;
} // end public Patient CreatePatient(Patient patient)
```

This seems to work and even connect the Patient to the County record via the foreign key.  It seems EF does some things here to achieve the desired end.